# root cause ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am trying to save the pdf on my local machine and that's happening. Although, the application is throwing a "ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages." exeption.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
    package com.ems.controllers;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.lowagie.text.*;
import com.lowagie.text.Font;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.document.AbstractPdfView;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Map;

import com.amazonaws.auth.PropertiesCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectResult;

public class FeedbackPDFView extends AbstractPdfView {

    @Override
    protected void buildPdfDocument(Map<String, Object> model, Document document, PdfWriter writer,
                                    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
        writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("G:/test/document.pdf"));
        writer.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.PDF_VERSION_1_7);
        document.open();

        String empID = String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("empID"));
        String firstName = (String) request.getAttribute("firstName");
        String lastName = (String) request.getAttribute("lastName");
        String emailAddress = (String) request.getAttribute("emailAddress");
        String designation = (String) request.getAttribute("designation");
        String managerFirstName = (String) request.getAttribute("managerFirstName");
        String managerLastName = (String) request.getAttribute("managerLastName");
        String managerID = String.valueOf(request.getAttribute("managerID"));
        String managerEmailAddress = (String) request.getAttribute("managerEmailAddress");
        String valueCreator = (String) request.getAttribute("valueCreator");
        String peopleDeveloper = (String) request.getAttribute("peopleDeveloper");
        String businessOperator = (String) request.getAttribute("businessOperator");
        String technicalSkills = (String) request.getAttribute("technicalSkills");
        String taskCompletionSkills = (String) request.getAttribute("taskCompletionSkills");
        String uninformedLease = (String) request.getAttribute("uninformedLease");
        String communicationSkills = (String) request.getAttribute("communicationSkills");
        String efficientAreas = (String) request.getAttribute("efficientAreas");
        String improvementAreas = (String) request.getAttribute("improvementAreas");


        Font font_helvetica_14_normal_black = new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 16, Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK);
        Font font_courier_14_italic_black = new Font(Font.COURIER, 16, Font.ITALIC, Color.BLACK);
        Font font_times_18_bold_black = new Font(Font.TIMES_ROMAN, 18, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK);

        Paragraph prg1 = new Paragraph("Performance Feedback", font_times_18_bold_black);
        Phrase phr1 = new Phrase("Personal Details", font_helvetica_14_normal_black);
        Paragraph prg2 = new Paragraph(" ", font_times_18_bold_black);

        Chunk c1 = new Chunk("EMPLOYEE ID:          ", font_courier_14_italic_black);
        Chunk c2 = new Chunk(empID, font_courier_14_italic_black);

        Chunk c35 = new Chunk("EMPLOYEE NAME:          ", font_courier_14_italic_black);
        Chunk c4 = new Chunk(firstName, font_courier_14_italic_black);
        Chunk c5 = new Chunk(lastName, font_courier_14_italic_black);


        Chunk c6 = new Chunk("EMPLOYEE EMAIL:          ", font_courier_14_italic_black);
        Chunk c7 = new Chunk(emailAddress, font_courier_14_italic_black);


        Chunk c8 = new Chunk("DESIGNATION:          ", font_courier_14_italic_black);
        Chunk c9 = new Chunk(designation, font_courier_14_italic_black);

        Phrase phr8 = new Phrase("Manager Details", font_helvetica_14_normal_black);

        Chunk c10 = new Chunk("MANAGER ID:          ", font_courier_14_italic_black);
        Chunk c11 = new Chunk(managerID, font_courier_14_italic_black);


        Chunk c12 = new Chunk("MANAGER NAME:          ", font_courier_14_italic_black);
        Chunk c13 = new Chunk(managerFirstName, font_courier_14_italic_black);
        Chunk c14 = new Chunk(managerLastName, font_courier_14_italic_black);


        Chunk c15 = new Chunk("MANAGER EMAIL:          ", font_courier_14_italic_black);
        Chunk c16 = new Chunk(managerEmailAddress, font_courier_14_italic_black);


        Chunk c17 = new Chunk("VALUE CREATOR:          ", font_courier_14_italic_black);
        Chunk c18 = new Chunk(valueCreator, font_courier_14_italic_black);


        Chunk c19 = new Chunk("PEOPLE DEVELOPER:          ", font_courier_14_italic_black);
        Chunk c20 = new Chunk(peopleDeveloper, font_courier_14_italic_black);


        Chunk c21 = new Chunk("BUSINESS OPERATOR:          ", font_courier_14_italic_black);
        Chunk c22 = new Chunk(businessOperator, font_courier_14_italic_black);


        Chunk c23 = new Chunk("COMMUNICATION SKILLS:          ", font_courier_14_italic_black);
        Chunk c24 = new Chunk(communicationSkills, font_courier_14_italic_black);


        Chunk c25 = new Chunk("TECHNICAL SKILLS:          ", font_courier_14_italic_black);
        Chunk c26 = new Chunk(technicalSkills, font_courier_14_italic_black);


        Chunk c27 = new Chunk("TASK COMPLETION SKILLS:          ", font_courier_14_italic_black);
        Chunk c28 = new Chunk(taskCompletionSkills, font_courier_14_italic_black);


        Chunk c29 = new Chunk("UNINFORMED LEAVES:          ", font_courier_14_italic_black);
        Chunk c30 = new Chunk(uninformedLease, font_courier_14_italic_black);


        Chunk c31 = new Chunk("EFFICIENT AREAS:          ", font_courier_14_italic_black);
        Chunk c32 = new Chunk(efficientAreas, font_courier_14_italic_black);


        Chunk c33 = new Chunk("IMPROVEMENT AREAS:          ", font_courier_14_italic_black);
        Chunk c34 = new Chunk(improvementAreas, font_courier_14_italic_black);

        document.add(prg1);
        document.add(prg2);
        document.add(phr1);
        document.add(prg2);
        document.add(c1);
        document.add(c2);

        document.add(prg2);
        document.add(c35);
        document.add(c4);
        document.add(c5);

        document.add(prg2);
        document.add(c6);
        document.add(c7);

        document.add(prg2);
        document.add(c8);
        document.add(c9);
        document.add(prg2);

        document.add(phr8);
        document.add(prg2);
        document.add(c10);
        document.add(c11);

        document.add(prg2);
        document.add(c12);
        document.add(c13);
        document.add(c14);

        document.add(prg2);
        document.add(c15);
        document.add(c16);

        document.add(prg2);
        document.add(prg2);


        document.add(prg2);
        document.add(c17);
        document.add(c18);

        document.add(prg2);
        document.add(c19);
        document.add(c20);

        document.add(prg2);
        document.add(c21);
        document.add(c22);

        document.add(prg2);
        document.add(c23);
        document.add(c24);

        document.add(prg2);
        document.add(c25);
        document.add(c26);

        document.add(prg2);
        document.add(c27);
        document.add(c28);

        document.add(prg2);
        document.add(c29);
        document.add(c30);

        document.add(prg2);
        document.add(c31);
        document.add(c32);

        document.add(prg2);
        document.add(c33);
        document.add(c34);
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you able to open document.pdf using pdf reader?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to view it using pdf reader.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I see you are writing it to a file.

Comment: can you past the complete stack track of the exception?

Comment: exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:894)
 org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

Comment: root cause

ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.